# get style from css, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I making JavaScript 3D animation using actual style. I create working code but, i can't run the code if style is in extended CSS file, so code run only when style is written in HTML code. There is a solution?

Working code[(olso on fiddle)](https://fiddle.jshell.net/cazzfvjf/25/):

HTML

```
<div id="background">
   <div class="example" style="transform-origin: 50% 50% -200px">
      <p class="num">Example</p>
   </div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 80px;
}

#background{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;    
}

.example:nth-child(1){
   transform: perspective(200px);
   transform-origin: 50% 50% -200px;
}


.background {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;

}

.num {
  display: inline-block;
  color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;


}
```

JavaScript

```
setInterval(function(){ move()}, 2000);

function move(){    
   var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
   var str = elem[0].style.transformOrigin;
   var res = str.split(" ");
   var pos = res[2].replace(/px/g, " ");
   var id = setInterval(frame, 20);

   function frame(){
     if (pos==500){
     clearInterval(id);
   }
   else {
    pos++;
    elem[0].style.transformOrigin = "50% 50%"+pos+"px";
   }
 }                                                                      
}
```

So as you see everything is working but, when i delete style from HTML code. I can see error in console: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Have you tryed to include CSS file as header in all your source code files?

Comment: Why down vote?  Did I forget to put some data?

Comment: Ye off corse I did that

Comment: Wrap the JS in a `document.onload`. Chances are, the JS runs before the CSS is loaded and so the CSS property doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [getComputedStyles](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle). That will allow you to see the CSS computed values. JS is not able to extract the CSS stylings directly from the DOM element, but needs to process the styles that has been applied to it.

Also you will need to use getPropertyValue('transform-origin') in order to access the desired attribute.

Your assign to str in order to get the 3rd value of the transform origin will look like:

```
    var str = getComputedStyle(elem[0]).getPropertyValue('transform-origin')
```

[Fiddle here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/0kw7hh1s/2/)

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Styles defined in CSS are not reflected in `style` property.

Comment: This is right, but there's no way to tell from the fiddle.

Comment: The fiddle just needed that tuning by getting the computed styles, the rest didn't show a bigger problem. So it was more of asserting why it wasn't working before. @TricksfortheWeb